# Как сделать чтобы ответ примера всегда был целым и был в заданном диапазоне?

Tags: javascript, node.js, алгоритм

Как сделать так, чтобы ответ примера всегда был цельным и был в диапазоне от 0 до 100?

Код:

```js
function rn() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

function example_generator(level) {
  const operator = {
    0: Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-',
    1: '*',
    2: '/',
    3: '%',
    4: `% ${this.rn()} ${
        [Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-', '*', '/'][
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
        ]
      }`,
  };
  return `${this.rn()} ${operator[level]} ${this.rn()}`;
}

console.log(example_generator(0));
console.log(example_generator(1));
console.log(example_generator(2));
console.log(example_generator(3));
console.log(example_generator(4));
```

Comment: У Вас в массиве три элемента.

Comment: *как сделать чтобы ответ примера всегда был в диапазоне от от 0 до 100* Проверять результат. При несоответствии - перегенерировать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все числа, результат и все промежуточные результаты от 1 до 100 включительно. Требуется предподсчёт некоторых значений, но в дальнейшем генерация работает быстро.

Распределение довольно хорошее. Для простых случаев (уровни 0-3) равномерное, для сложных (4-7) - равномерное по второй операции и равномерное среди способов получить её первый аргумент (но не равномерное относительно всех возможных примеров). Если добавить веса, то можно допилить до полностью равномерного.

```js
var lim = 100

var ops = {
  '+': [],
  '-': [],
  '*': [],
  '/': [],
  '%': [],
}

var byRes = {
  '+': Array(lim + 1),
  '-': Array(lim + 1),
  '*': Array(lim + 1),
  '/': Array(lim + 1),
  '%': Array(lim + 1),
}

var fs = {
  '+'(x, y) { return x + y },
  '-'(x, y) { return x - y },
  '*'(x, y) { return x * y },
  '/'(x, y) { return x / y },
  '%'(x, y) { return x % y },
}

~function prepare() {
  for (var x=1; x<=lim; ++x) {
    for (var y=1; y<=lim; ++y) {
      for (var op of Object.keys(fs)) {
        var res = fs[op](x, y)
        if (res >= 1 && res <= lim && res === ~~res) {
          ops[op].push([op, x, y])
          void (byRes[op][res] = byRes[op][res] || []).push([op, x, y])
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  var missing = 0
  
  for (var res=1; res<=lim; ++res) {
    for (var op of Object.keys(byRes)) {
      if (!(res in byRes[op])) {
        console.log(`Unable to get ${res} using '${op}'`)
        ++missing
      }
    }
  }
  
  if (missing > 3) { // +1, -100, %100
    throw new Error("The map is incomlete, consider reworking algorithm")
  }
}()

function randof(...arrs) {
  var len = arrs.reduce((r, a) => r + a.length, 0)
  var i = Math.random() * len | 0
  return arrs.find(a => i < a.length || (i -= a.length, false))[i]
}

var simpleLevels = [
  [ops['+'], ops['-']],
  [ops['*']],
  [ops['/']],
  [ops['%']],
]

function generate(lev) {
  if (lev < simpleLevels.length) {
    var [op, x, y] = randof(...simpleLevels[lev])
    return [fs[op](x, y), `${x} ${op} ${y}`]
  }

  var lev2 = 0
  var levOp1 = '*/%'[lev - simpleLevels.length]
  
  while(1) {
    var [op2, l, z] = randof(...simpleLevels[lev2])
    
    if (!byRes[levOp1][l]) {
      console.log(`Retry at level ${lev}`) // Очень редко
      continue
    }
    
    var [op1, x, y] = randof(byRes[levOp1][l])
    return [fs[op2](fs[op1](x, y), z), `${x} ${op1} ${y} ${op2} ${z}`]
  }
}

var LEVELS_COUNT = simpleLevels.length * 2 - 1

setInterval(() => {
  var lev = Math.random() * LEVELS_COUNT | 0
  var [r, e] = generate(lev)
  if ((0,eval)(e) !== r) throw new Error(`${e} is not equal to ${r}`)
  console.log(`[${lev}]   ${e} = ${r}`)
}, 1000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: `'+'(x, y) { return x + y },` → `'+': (x, y) => x + y,` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, можно, а смысл?

Comment: [Чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113089/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-kristalkillplay).

Answer (score 6):

Все числа, результат и все промежуточные результаты от 1 до 100 включительно.

А вот удачность распределения не гарантирую. Вполне возможно, что некоторые комбинации выпадают чаще других.

```js
function rand(min, max) {
  return min + ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))
}

var fs = {
  '+'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    var x = rand(min, max - 1)
    var y = rand(1, max - x)
    return [x + y, `${x} + ${y}`]
  },
  '-'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    var x = rand(min + 1, lim)
    var y = rand(Math.max(1, x - max), x - min)
    return [x - y, `${x} - ${y}`]
  },
  '*'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    if (min !== 1) throw new Error("Not implemented")
    var x = rand(1, max) // TODO: поменять распределение
    var y = rand(1, max / x | 0)
    return [x * y, `${x} * ${y}`]
  },
  '/'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    if (min !== 1) throw new Error("Not implemented")
    var r = rand(1, max) // TODO: поменять распределение
    var y = rand(1, max / r | 0)
    var x = r * y
    return [x / y, `${x} / ${y}`]
  },
  '%'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    var x = rand(1, lim)
    var y = rand(min + 1, max)
    if (x % y < min && (x += min) % y < min) x = min
    return [x % y, `${x} % ${y}`]
  },
  '*+'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    var [x, e] = this['*'](min, max - 1, lim)
    var y = rand(1, max - x)
    return [x + y, `${e} + ${y}`]
  },
  '*-'(min = 1, max = 100, lim = 100) {
    var [x, e] = this['*'](min, max, lim)
    var y = rand(Math.max(1, x - max), x - min)
    return [x - y, `${e} - ${y}`]
  },
}

var levels = [
  ['+', '-'],
  ['*'],
  ['/'],
  ['%'],
  ['*+', '*-'],
]

function randof(arr) {
  return arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0]
}

function generate(lev) {
  return fs[randof(levels[lev])]()
}

setInterval(() => {
  var lev = Math.random() * levels.length | 0
  var [r, e] = generate(lev)
  if ((0,eval)(e) !== r) throw new Error(`${e} is not equal to ${r}`)
  console.log(`[${lev}]   ${e} = ${r}`)
}, 1000)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113090/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy--------).

Answer (score 4):

```js
function rn() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

function example_generator(level) {
  const operator = {
    0: Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-',
    1: '*',
    2: '/',
    3: '%',
    4: `% ${this.rn()} ${
        [Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-', '*', '/'][
          Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
        ]
      }`,
  };
  
  let exp = `${this.rn()} ${operator[level]} ${this.rn()}`;
  var r = eval(exp);
  if (r < 0)
    exp = `${exp} + ${-r}`;
  if (r > 100)
    exp = `${exp} - ${r-100}`;
  
  return exp;
}

console.log(example_generator(0));
console.log(example_generator(1));
console.log(example_generator(2));
console.log(example_generator(3));
console.log(example_generator(4));
```

Comment: Простите что только сейчас это говорю,я не правильно задал вопрос,как сделать чтобы ответ был цельным в диапазоне от 1 до 100 *,прошу прощения

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Я не знаю, что такое "цельным".

Comment: Чтобы не было 0.3457345 а были целые числа типа 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 и тд

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Что Вы уже сделали в этом направлении?

Comment: ```
    if (r < 0 || r > 100 || r.toFixed(0) != r) {
      return example_generator(level);
    }
```

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Это что?

Comment: Проверка на то что если ответ меньше 0 или больше 100 или если r.toFixed(0) (например число 0.3 оно округлит до 0) не ровняется R,то функция заново запускается

Comment: @KristalkillPlay И как, работает?

Comment: Да абсолют,работает(пока не видел сбоев)

Comment: Я прокрутил функцию 1000 раз,ни разу не было числа которое не целое,или больше 100 или меньше 0

Answer (score 1):

Допиленый ответ @Igor ` а

```js
function rn() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

function generator(level) {
  const operator = {
    0: Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-',
    1: '*',
    2: '/',
    3: '%',
    4: `% ${rn()} ${
      [Math.random() > 0.5 ? '+' : '-', '*', '/'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
    }`,
  };

  let exp = `${rn()} ${operator[level]} ${rn()}`;
  var r = eval(exp);
  if (r < 0 || r > 100 || r.toFixed(0) != r) {
    return generator(level);
  }
  return [r, exp];
}
  const zero = generator(0);
  const one = generator(1);
  const two = generator(2);
  const three = generator(3);
  const four = generator(4);
  console.log(`${zero[1]} = ${zero[0]}`);
  console.log(`${one[1]} = ${one[0]}`);
  console.log(`${two[1]} = ${two[0]}`);
  console.log(`${three[1]} = ${three[0]}`);
  console.log(`${four[1]} = ${four[0]}`);
```